# How can I find data pattern matches in all fields/tables in an oracle database?

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

Specifically, I am trying to find any credit card numbers that have been typed into text fields of any table in the database.  This code below works for a single table where I know the primary key is "ID", but I cannot find a way to make this dynamic so that I can loop through many hundreds of table and rows.

```
drop table tab1 purge;

create table tab1(id number primary key, col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20), col3 varchar2(20));

Insert into TAB1 Values (1, 'No card here', 'Hello', 'nothing');

Insert into TAB1 Values (2, '1111222233334444', 'Visa', 'Hello');

Insert into TAB1 Values (3, 'Hello', 'MasterCard', '1111 2222 3333 4444');

Insert into TAB1 Values (4, 'Hello', '1111-2222-3333-4444', 'Visa');

Insert into TAB1 Values (5, 'Amex', 'Hello', '1111 222222 33333');

Insert into TAB1 Values (6, '111122222233333', 'Amex', 'Hello');

Insert into TAB1 Values (7, 'nothing', 'No card here', 'Hello');

COMMIT;


declare

    myrow clob;

begin

    for i in (select id from tab1) loop
        select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from tab1 where id=' || i.id) into myrow from dual;
        if regexp_instr(myrow,'[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{6}[ -]?[0-9]{5}') > 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('May have found one: ' || to_char(i.id));
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Wait, you want to go through ALL varchar2 columns of ALL tables in your database?

Comment: @piezol: classic request. The question I closed-as-dup for is ten years old, making it one of the earliest Oracle questions/answers on SO.

Comment: Bob Jarvis, Could you kindly point me to the answer from 10 years ago? I could not find the answer and have a similar issue 10 years after the original post.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Todd It is attached to your question (look at the top of the page).